# SCSS in Svelte not recognized by Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

VSCode does not recognize the scss that I include within a svelte file. It thinks they are css styles and, the first nesting css that it meets, gives me error.
I tried to disable the validation of the css in the settings through but it doesn't seem to have any effect: "css.validate": false,
The svelte application works correctly, either by launching it locally or by compiling the bundle for production (it's not a problem of my code).
It's just a problem with how VSCode controls my styles. For this problem, most of my svelte components seem wrong even if they are not really.
To compile styles like scss I include the attribute `type="text/scss"` to the tag:

```
<style type="text/scss">
```

[image: SCSS in Svelte not recognized by Visual Studio Code]

[image: Another svelte scss false error]

All errors have code: "`css-syntax-error`".
I think that the reason is because VS Code doesn't recognize that it's SCSS and not CSS.

I have these extensions for sass in svelte:

- SCSS IntelliSense
- Beautify css/scss/sass/less
- Live SASS Compiler
- Svelte plugin 0.9.3

[image: Svelte plugin version]

My VSCode settings:

```
{
  "svelte.language-server.runtime": "......",
  "scss.lint.important": "warning",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "css.completion.triggerPropertyValueCompletion": false,
  "css.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": false,
  "css.lint.argumentsInColorFunction": "ignore",
  "css.lint.hexColorLength": "ignore",
  "css.lint.duplicateProperties": "warning",
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker",
  "css.validate": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "css.fileExtensions": [
    "css",
    "scss"
  ],
  "beautify.options": {

  },
}
```

Comment: Which Svelte Plugin do use use? "Svelte" or "Svelte Beta"? I recommend to use the latter as it's going to become the official Svelte Plugin. Also, what exactly does the error say (if you hover over it; including the error source which is to the right of the message in gray)? General note: SASS is not supported, only SCSS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my question with more informations.
I use the 0.9.3 version of the plugin from James Birtles (I have included a screenshot above). Is it the correct version?
I have those errors in all the svelte components with SCSS styles but only for the first SCSS code fragment. The error code is the same for all: css-syntax-error (like VS Code doesn't not recognize it like scss). I'm not using SASS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error it seems that the preprocessing of your svelte file failed. You need a `svelte.config.js` at the root of your project. The Plugin uses this to preprocess files.

If you use this preprocessor plugin for svelte https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-preprocess , setting it up is as easy as this:

svelte.config.js:

```
const sveltePreprocess = require("svelte-preprocess");

module.exports = {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One up!